# Tag <img>. Ao carregar uma imagem do banco ela aparece deitada

Tags: html, css

Algumas fotos que são carregadas do banco em minha tag `<img>` aparecem deitadas (landscape), mas quando abro a imagem do PC ela está correta na posição vertical.

Essa é a parte que recebe a imagem.

**HTML**

```
<img 
    src="<?php echo $caminhoFotoEditaUsuario; ?>"  
    class="img-thumbnail imagem-grupo-cadastro"
    id="fotoUsuario" 
    name="fotoUsuario"
>
```

**CSS**

```css
.imagem-grupo-cadastro{
    width :140px; 
    height : 140px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente a foto original está mesmo deitada, e o visualizador do PC está rotacionando automaticamente baseado na flag de orientação da imagem, mas o browser não.

Comment: Se for mesmo esse o caso, sua Aplicação não tiver limitação quanto a versão dos browsers os quais a visualizarão E reprocessar cada umas imagens for um empecilho, a [propriedade transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) do CSS3 pode quebrar um galho.

Comment: Uma forma de resolver sem precisar modificar a imagem, é obter o exif via JavaScript e detectar se deve ou não rotacionar.

Uma pergunta similar no SO-en: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images

Comment: no google, pesquisei pelas palavras "jquery image exif auto rotate".

Comment: Caro @Leandro, sei que faz muito tempo e já deve ter resolvido, mas recomendo isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170492/3635, são duas soluções diferentes, pois nem sempre vai ter o exif.

Answer (score 6):

Normalmente a foto foi tirada "deitada", e a orientação correta marcada na tag `orientation` do [EXIF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format).

O problema é que a foto realmente é gravada "deitada" dependendo do dispositivo (mais comumente celulares e *tablets*), e apenas é "anotado" na referida Tag qual é a orientação correta.

A consequência é o que você percebeu na sua aplicação. Em certos visualizadores, a imagem aparece na orientação correta, porém, dependendo navegador vai aparecer "deitada", pois a tag EXIF é ignorada em certas situações, e em outras não.

A solução é abrir as images em alguma aplicação gráfica, e corrigir a posição. Preferencialmente eliminando a orientação do [EXIF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format), para não causar mais ambiguidades.

Esta é uma imagem que tem orientação EXIF. Clique nela para visualizar fora do `<img>`, e teste em mais de um *browser*:

[image: teste exif]

Um bom teste é salvar no PC e conferir as miniaturas, e abrir em softwares diferentes, para ver como é inconsistente o comportamento da tag.

- No IE11, por exemplo, aparece sempre deitada.
- No Opera 34 aparece deitada na postagem, mas em aba separada aparece em pé. Já no Opera12, aparece deitada em qualquer situação.
- No visualizador do Windows 7 e nas miniaturas, aparece deitada.
- Essa mesma foto que foi salva no Windows 7 e está aparecendo deitada, ao abrir com o Photoshop CS6 aparece em pé.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Ver no PC nao quer dizer nada. Já abri fotos deitadas aqui que ao abrir no PC o programa gira ela automaticamente.

Comment: @DavidFernandes eu deixei um comentário explicando isso embaixo da pergunta em 2014, mas como vi que tá aparecendo um monte de resposta aqui, achei melhor colocar essa explicação. Isso acontecia bastante com iPhone, por exemplo. Sei que o iMagik também rodava automático, e isso era uma confusão. Não sei como tá hoje, mas depois de fazer uns testes, atualizo a resposta com mais detalhes. Vou ter que linkar uma foto de exemplo fora do SOpt acho, pois se fizer upload pelo site, ela perde as caracteristicas na conversão. A regra geral é "em caso de dúvida, tire a foto na orientação normal" :)

Comment: Pois é. Já vi isso aqui várias vezes. Não lembro se foi no Photoshop ou no IrfanView, mas a foto era deitada e ao abrir, apareceu "em pé".. rs

Comment: Mas a questão é: impossível uma imagem vir diferente do que está no servidor... a nao ser que algum script a altere no meio do caminho.. :)

Comment: Tem que ver se o navegador Lê isso.

Comment: @DavidFernandes pus um exemplo. No Opera atual, essa imagem usa o EXIF se vc abrir em aba separada, mas nao usa dentro do IMG.

Comment: Qual imagem????

Comment: Verdade. No Photoshop ela aparece deitada. Já no IrfanView aparece em pé, e também aparece em pé no thumb do Windows.

Comment: Mas acho que o cerne da questão é: quem vai enviar a imagem deveria trata-la antes de enviar, e não enviar como foi tirada.

Comment: É, mais ou menos isso que eu comentei no 4º parágrafo. Inclusive, até para tirar dados desnecessários da imagem. Já ouvi histórias de gente que se complicou por ter postado foto "anonimamente" sem perceber que tinha coordenadas de GPS dentro. Virou um "anônimo" de endereço conhecido. Inclusive, numa dessas a pessoa pode tirar uma foto de um elefante raro, e estar entregando o coitado do bicho pra caçadores só de postar a foto na internet. O bom é limpar o EXIF e todos os dados extras da imagem, até por economia de banda.

Answer (score -2):

Experimente remover o height:

```
.imagem-grupo-cadastro{
    width :140px; 
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Como já foi sugerido, provavelmente a foto está realmente deitada.

Caso seja um problema com todas as imagens, é muito provável que o script que está enviando as imagens esteja enviando-as de forma incorreta.

Uma forma de resolver seu problema seria utilizando o css-transform, com rotate:

```
.imagem-grupo-cadastro {
    transform: rotate(xdeg);
}
```

Onde x é a quantidade de graus, que no seu caso seria 90 ou -90, dependendo para qual lado a sua imagem foi rotacionada.

Lembre-se também de usar as variantes `-ms-transform` e `-webkit-transform`.

Mas deixo bem claro que isso seria mais uma "gambiarra" para resolver seu problema, caso seja urgente. O ideal seria saber o motivo de sua imagem ter sido carregada de forma errada.

Comment: Se o problema for no script que envia a foto, tem que corrigir o script, senão todas as fotos vao ser afetadas, inclusive as que forem carregadas corretamente.