# Rotação de fotos em PHP

Tags: php

Como faço para rotacionar um arquivo de foto já salvo no servidor.
As fotos as vezes vem deitadas e eu as quero em pé ou vice-versa.
Meu sistema é em PHP.

Comment: Qual o código estas a testar ?

Comment: leia esse post aqui http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito vaga. Você precisa ser mais específico adicionando códigos etc.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que não adianta rotacionar com PHP, você teria que criar um algorítimo inteligente para detectar que a foto esta ou -90° ou +90° ou +180°, o PHP não vai conseguir fazer sozinho (e nem nenhuma linguagem).

Imagine que você tem uma foto que está +180°, então você pode usar `imagerotate($imagem, 180)`, a próxima foto estará a -90°, então o correto seria usar `imagerotate($imagem, 90)`, o qual apenas rotacionar de forma errada.

Para maioria das fotos **não é possivel** rotacionar (leia o final da resposta para ver a solução alternativa), ainda sim algumas fotos se vindas diretamente de uma *câmera digital* (ou celular avançado) e tiver os cabeçalho `exif`, será possível rotacionar (se tiver passado por um editor de imagem menos avançado talvez os dados não sejam os esperados) então pode tentar algo como esta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9207128/1518921):

```
function corrigeOrientacao($filename)
{
    $exif = exif_read_data($filename);
    $rotation = null;

    if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
        switch ($exif['Orientation'])
        {
            case 3:
                $rotation = 180;
                break;

            case 6:
                $rotation = -90;
                break;

            case 8:
                $rotation = 90;
                break;
        }
    }

    if ($rotation !== null) {
        $target = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        $target = imagerotate($target, $rotation, 0);

        //Salva por cima da imagem original
        imagejpeg($target, $filename);

        //libera da memória
        imagedestroy($target);
        $target = null;
    }
}
```

Usando:

```
corrigeOrientacao('pasta/minhafoto.jpg');
```

As funções com prefixo `exif_` podem estar desabilitadas, para isto procure no PHP.INI do teu servidor estas linhas e tire o `;` da frente:

```
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
```

Se for Unix-like é assim:

```
extension=mbstring.so
extension=exif.so
```

Se for PHP7.2+, tanto windows quanto unix-like é assim (para ambos):

```
extension=mbstring
extension=exif
```

Depois de salvar as modificações é necessário reiniciar o servidor Apache/Nginx/IIS

---

### Passando a tarefa para o usuário (resolvendo com JavaScript/front-end)

Todavia como eu disse muitas fotos não terão o `exif`, ou poderão ser eventualmente afetados por algum editor de imagem, o **mais é garantido** é passar a tarefa para o usuário em uma aplicações front-end com [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) e [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), todavia existem plugins prontos, como:

Um plugin se acaso usar Angular.js:

- https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop

Se usa jQuery

- http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função `imagerotate()`.

Por exemplo:

```
// Define o básico
$graus = 90;
$arquivo = "imagem.jpg";

// Cria a imagem de JPEG (se for PNG deve usar imagecreatefrompng(), por exemplo)
$imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($arquivo);

// Rotaciona
$rotate = imagerotate($imagem, $graus, 0);
```

Veja a documentação das ["Funções GD"](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.image.php) e especificamente do [`imagerotate()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagerotate.php).