# Upload de imagem rotaciona imagem vertical

Tags: php, imagem

Tenho um script que faz o upload das imagens e cria 2 arquivos: largura 1200 e largura 50.

Ele funciona normalmente, mas quando a foto é vertical (altura maior que largura) ele rotaciona a imagem no upload sozinho.

Notei que mesmo fazendo upload direto pelo cpanel, quando abre a imagem ela está rotacionada.

Se eu abrir a imagem no photohop e salvar como uma nova, aí funciona normal

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34866/tag-img-ao-carregar-uma-imagem-do-banco-ela-aparece-deitada

Answer (score 0):

A câmera salva informações na coluna Orientation como a imagem deve ser rotacionada para melhor visualização, alguns programas leem essa informação e processam de acordo.

Abaixo a visualização de uma parte dessa cabeçalho.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o campo Orientation. Nesse caso esta normal e a foto não será rotacionada.

Baixe o programa [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/index.php) para ajuda-lo a alterar essa informação.

Procure maiores informações sobre isso [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif).